# Generate sequences number with repetition

Tags: c#, linq, sequence

I have the following code:

```
var result = AllSequences(1, 10, 3);

public static IEnumerable<List<int>> AllSequences(int start, int end, int size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return Enumerable.Repeat<List<int>>(new List<int>(), 1);

    return from i in Enumerable.Range(start, end - size - start + 2)
           from seq in AllSequences(i, end, size - 1)
           select new List<int> { i }.Concat(seq).ToList();
}
```

Result:

```
1,1,1
1,1,2
1,1,3
1,1,4
....
2,2,2
2,2,3
2,2,4
```

But before coming to this sequence, wish you were like this:

```
2,1,1
2,1,2
2,1,3
2,1,4
.....
```

I'm having trouble generating sequence is, I'm using LINQ to gain performance in this loop

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization, and how do you know LINQ would gain performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question but if you want the sequence to run through each digit from 1 to 10, for all permutations try something like this.

I'm not advocating the use of LINQ here, just trying to make as few changes to your code as possible.

```
    public static IEnumerable<List<int>> AllSequences(int start, int end, int size)
    {
        if (size == 0)
            return Enumerable.Repeat<List<int>>(new List<int>(), 1);

        return from i in Enumerable.Range(start, end)
               from seq in AllSequences(start, end, size - 1)
               select new List<int> { i }.Concat(seq).ToList();
    }
```

Results will be

```
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
... etc
1, 1, 10
1, 2, 1
1, 2, 2
... etc
1, 10, 8
1, 10, 9
1, 10, 10
2, 1, 1
2, 1, 2 
.... etc
10, 10, 10
```